# d3.js bar chart - show/hide bars on legend click. how to filter correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a bar chart that changes depending on dropdown selections. The dropdown selections filter my data file.

Then, I'm showing/hiding the bars in the chart when the corresponding legend item is clicked. The show/hide is working. The problem is that the year data is not being filtered correctly. When clicking on the legend items, the data filtering that happened when the year was chosen from the dropdown is disregarded. I'm not sure why.

How to correct this?

My code is below, and here is a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gMa09b2jO9shxCbXDaFD?p=preview

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <div id="dropdown">
    <div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_custom" id="indSelectors">
    <label>Dimension:</label>
    <select size="1" id="dimensions" class=" validate['required']" title="" type="select" name="style">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
    <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    </select>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="error-message-style"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondaryDrop">
      <div id="Fruit"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
        <label>Fruit</label>
          <select class="inds">
            <option value="">- Select -</option>
            <option value="apples">apples</option>
            <option value="pears">pears</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div id="Vegetables"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub1">
        <label>Vegetables</label>
          <select class="inds">
            <option value="">- Select -</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">tomatoes</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="error-message-style-sub-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tertiaryDrop">
      <div id="apples"  class="style-sub-2"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub2">
        <label>Year</label>
          <select class="years">
            <option value="">- Select a Year -</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div id="pears"  class="style-sub-2"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub2">
        <label>Year</label>
          <select class="years">
            <option value="">- Select a Year -</option>
            <option value="1900">1900</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div id="tomatoes"  class="style-sub-2"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub2">
        <label>Year</label>
          <select class="years">
            <option value="">- Select a Year -</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div id="error-message-style-sub-2"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="legendContainer" class="legendContainer">
      <svg id="legend"></svg>
    </div>
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
      <p><span id="state"></span></p>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

js:

```
$("#dimensions").change ( function () {
        var targID  = $(this).val ();
        $("div.style-sub-1").hide ();
        $('#' + targID).show ();
    } );

    $(".inds").change ( function () {
        var targID  = $(this).val ();
        $("div.style-sub-2").hide ();
        $('#' + targID).show ();
    } );

    function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
      var result = [];
      for (var foo in json) {
        if (json[foo][key] === value) {
          result.push(json[foo]);
        }
      }
      return result;
    }

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 130, left: 160},
        width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        padding = 0.25;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right], padding);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(10);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;

        json.forEach(function(d) {
            d.year = +d.year;
            d.value = +d.value;
        });

    var yr;

        $('.inds')
                .on("change", function () {

                    var prod = $(this).val();
              console.log("prod:", prod);

                    data = filterJSON(json, 'produce', prod);

              console.log("data: ", data);
              updateGraph(data);


                    $('.years')
                            .on("change", function () {

                                var yr = $(this).val();
                          yr = +yr;

                                data1 = filterJSON(data, 'year', yr);

                          updateGraph(data1, yr);
                            });

        });

    // data = filterJSON(json, 'produce', 'apples');
    // data1 = filterJSON(data, 'year', 2015);
    // updateGraph(data1);

    });

    function updateGraph(data1, yr) {
      console.log("year: ", yr);

      console.log("data1: ", data1);

      data1.sort(function(a,b) {return a.value-b.value;});

      x.domain(data1.map(function(d) { return d.state; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data1, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

      var result = data1.filter(function(d){
                      return $("." + d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')).attr("fill") != "#cccccc"
                      // matching the data with selector status
                    })
      console.log("result: ", result);

      var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
          .data(result, function(d){return d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')});

        bars.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + x.rangeBand() + 5;
                    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;
                    //Update the tooltip position and value
                    d3.select("#tooltip")
                        .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                        .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                        .select("#state")
                        .text(d.state + ": " + d.produce + ": " + d.year + ": " + d.value);
                    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
              })
              .on("mouseout", function() {
                    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
              });

      bars.transition()
          .attr("id", function(d){ return 'tag'+d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '');})
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.state); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

        bars.exit().remove();

      // LEGEND GROUPS
      var legendGroups = d3.select("#legend")
        .selectAll(".legendGroup")
        .data(data1, function(d){
          return d.state; // always try and use a key function to uniquely identify
        });

      var enterGroups = legendGroups
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","legendGroup");

      legendGroups
        .exit()
        .remove();

      legendGroups
        .attr("transform",function(d,i){
           return "translate(10," + (10 + i* 15) + ")"; // position the whole group
         });

      enterGroups.append("text")
        .text(function(d){return d.state;})
        .attr("x", 15)
        .attr("y", 10);

      enterGroups
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .attr("fill",function(d) {
            return "#0000ff";
        })
        .attr("class", function(d,i){return "legendcheckbox " + d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,|\.+/g, '')})
        .on("click", function(d){
              d.active = !d.active;
              d3.select(this).attr("fill", function(d){
                if(d3.select(this).attr("fill")  == "#cccccc"){
                  return "#0000ff";
                }else {
                  return "#cccccc";
                }
              })


            var result = data1.filter(function(d, yr){
                          return $("." + d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')).attr("fill") != "#cccccc"
                        })
                  console.log("data1 after legend click", data1);
                  console.log("result after legend click: ", result);

            x.domain(result.map(function(d) { return d.state; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(result, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

            svg.select(".x.axis")
              .transition()
              .call(xAxis);

           svg.selectAll(".bar")
             .data(result, function(d){return d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,|\.+/g, '')})
             .enter()
             .append("rect")
             .attr("class", "bar")
             .on("mouseover", function(d) {
               var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + x.rangeBand() + 5;
               var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + height / 2;
               d3.select("#tooltip")
                 .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                 .style("top", yPosition + "px")
                 .select("#state")
                 .text(d.state + ": " + d.produce + ": " + d.year + ": " + d.value);
               d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
             })
             .on("mouseout", function() {
               d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
             });

          svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .transition()
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.state); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

          svg.selectAll(".bar").data(result, function(d){return d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,|\.+/g, '')}).exit().remove()

        }); // end on click

        svg.selectAll(".axis").remove();



      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("value");
    };
```

data (.json file) follows this format:

```
    [{
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1900,
      "value":"131"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":1950,
      "value":"231"
    },
    {
      "state":"Maine",
      "produce":"apples",
      "year":2000,
      "value":"191"
    }...
```

The full data file can be seen in the Plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a global variable `currentData`:

```
var currentData = [];

//set the currentData in the update
function updateGraph(data1, yr) {
  currentData = data1;
```

Then in legend click do filter on currentData:

```
var result = currentData.filter(function(d, yr){
                      return $("." + d.state.replace(/\s|\(|\)|\'|\,+/g, '')).attr("fill") != "#cccccc"
                    })
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/JUaLXmeCvHh0zUmrKClQ?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome, works beautifully. Thanks so much for your help on this!